# Understanding the theme details in style.css

Tags: themes, css

I'm developing a theme for a friend, and I'm not sure what to put for the author, author uri, etc. Here is the Twenty Ten code:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Ten
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: The 2010 default theme for WordPress.
Author: wordpressdotorg
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Version: 1.0
Tags: black, blue, white, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-header, custom-background, threaded-comments, sticky-post, translation-ready, microformats, rtl-language-support, editor-style, custom-menu (optional)

License:
License URI:

General comments (optional).
*/
```

- For Author, is that the blog owner, or the theme creator?
- Author URI, is that the blog owner's personal website, or the creator's?
- License & License URI, these are not open source. How do I specify that?

Answer (score 3):

Prince's answer is technically true, but doesn't answer your specific questions. In the interest of getting you to learn more about WordPress, I'll get those:

> For Author, is that the blog owner, or the theme creator?

This should represent the theme author/creator.

> Author URI, is that the blog owner's personal website, or the creator's?

Again, if the author = theme creator, this should then be the theme creator's web site.

> License & License URI, these are not open source. How do I specify that?

You can specify whatever you want, but themes inherit the WordPress and parent theme licenses. Learn more:

- http://wordpress.org/news/2009/07/themes-are-gpl-too/
- http://make.wordpress.org/themes/guidelines/guidelines-license-theme-name-credit-links-up-sell-themes/
- http://torquemag.io/youve-been-gpld/

Answer (score -1):

only thing required is

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Ten
*/
```

rest things are optional.